# Get the image path in fluid

Tags: image, typo3, fluid

in my fluid template I create an image with

```
<f:media file=" {post.teaserAssetsWide.0}" width="708" height="398" />
```

Is there a way to get just the path of the image like "domain.com/path.jpg" ?

Edit: **{post.teaserAssetsSquare.0.originalResource.publicUrl}** is the relative path for the image. But the domain is still missing

Comment: You can get image path like this in fluid. **{object.image.originalResource.publicUrl}**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to just add this paths in your fluid template like below. you don't need to add your domain name. You domain name will be automatically added in your paths.

Just added `absolute = '1'` for full paths.

```
<f:image src="{object.image.originalResource.publicUrl}" alt="{object.image.originalResource.title}" width="640" height="291" treatIdAsReference="1" />
```

Or try to below for **absolute paths**.

```
<f:image image="{post.teaserAssetsSquare.0}" title="{post.teaserAssetsSquare.0.originalResource.title}" absolute="1" />
```

For get just **image paths**.

```
<f:uri.image image="{post.teaserAssetsSquare.0}" width="400" height="375" absolute="1" />
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want just the url of the image for a RSS feed :)

Comment: just added **absolute = 'true'** attributes in f:image

Comment: **{post.teaserAssetsSquare.0.originalResource.publicUrl}** is now the string that I need. But this is relative

Comment: Can I get the Url without the img-tags? That would be great

Comment: For get image url see my latest answers.

Comment: awesome! Thank you so much